# Image in CSS file. Using Spring MVC . How to load this ?

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, sass

I have code in CSS:

```
.container {
  background-image: url("resources/images/web.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 1580px;
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

TREE:

```
   ----webapp
       |resources
           |images
              |web.jpg
```

But when i go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateExampleweb/index
```

I don't see this background.
My xml is correct configured, because when i write:

```
 <img class="logo" src="resources/images/blackcat.jpg"
```

They see me image of cat

But image backgroud in CSS file, I don't see. Why ?
How to pair with JSP SPRING MVC

Comment: Where is the CSS file located at? Are we talking about inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Spring Resource Mapping" in your configuration 
example;

```
 < mvc:resources mapping="**/resources/**" location="/resources/"
cache-period="31556926"/>
```

use in jsp;

```
< img class="logo" src="/**resources**/images/blackcat.jpg"
```

I was hoping I can help

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

ADD this to xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```